Google Cloud Datastore - com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Non-protobuf error
I am using Objectify, a Java data access API designed for Google Cloud Datastore, in my Java application running on Cloud Run. Over the past week, I have encountered around 400 occurrences of the following exception during random read operations for different entities.
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Non-protobuf error
That’s an error.The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.That’s all we know.HTTP status code was 502.


Observations:

The error occurs during random (mostly read) queries.
The frequency of the error has increased the last couple of weeks, with around 400 occurrences in the past week (in a total of around a million http requests).
Over the past months I had random occurrences of this error but in way lower numbers (less than 10 per month).
I don't think I am exceeding any quotas (even during peak times, the application handles around 150 queries per second, based on the monitoring dashboards provided by Google.).

Google suggests to implement a retry logic (I have a retry mechanism with exponential backoff for my async google tasks handling exceptions like this one, but this is not something I can implement for all the customer facing APIs).
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Super weird. Are you using the very latest Google cloud library version?

This error (are they all the same?) seems definitive "temporary error" "try again" and that you must do. It's possible that Datastore has experienced a period of decreased stability but you'll only get confirmation of this from Google support.  If you repeatedly try the same request without backing off, Google's SLA doesn't count the subsequent errors. Your question is unclear on this. It's unlikely to be quota or contention as, I think (!?), these would give different errors. Unfortunately, you really must build your app for resilience against this type of error.

@stickfigure I am currently using objectify version 6.0.9. The latest version is 6.1.1, and I plan to update to it early next week after testing the changes. This update includes some recommended modifications related to upcoming deprecations in Key creation methods.

@DazWilkin for the customer-facing part, I don't believe this is the case. While it’s acceptable to have to retry for asynchronous tasks, having the UI slow down just to retry simple read operations would be problematic. In the past, I encountered different errors due to contention, which I resolved for specific entities.

@XII Seems like your issue needs internal logs to check the route cause. feel free to contact Google Support

@SathiAiswarya Thanks for your suggestion. Out of curiosity, do you have similar experience, and is that why you recommend contacting Google support? Whenever I reach out to them for other issues, their support typically just reiterates publicly available information. For instance, I'm quite sure they would suggest adding a retry mechanism.
